# Timestamp Question

Tags: blockchain, block-explorer

The timestamp for block 129587 is 2017-01-08 22:01:42 UTC : http://moneroblocks.info/block/1219587

One block later 129588 the timestamp is 2017-01-08 21:58:37 UTC :  http://moneroblocks.info/block/1219588

Why has the later block an earlier timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

Synchronizing time across machines is difficult due to clock drift and network latencies. The timestamp of a block in Monero is specified by the miner, and the nodes only enforce that the timestamp of a [new block is greater than the median of the last 60 blocks](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp#L2948). If the nodes used their local clock to enforce timestamp, there would be some risk of disagreement of the validity of the newest block, and therefore a potential chain fork could result. Searching [anything related to Bitcoin](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_timestamp) would be of use too, because identical issues with time are present on that system.

A system could require that the timestamps strictly increase or remain equal, but that could force a miner to put a timestamp that they viewed as incorrect in subsequent blocks.